# Inspect Page Doesn't Reflect Color on Web Page

Tags: joomla-3.4, templates, css

I am driving to change the background color where it says Module1:Initial Configuration. I have changed the css to 0088cc as shown in the image, but the color blue doesn't show on my web page.

The link is here
http://www.keylooplabs.com/index.php/ed-serv/settings-2

Can someone let me know where I'm going wrong.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Please specify anything like extension or template that you using because it's not native Joomla behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS we have something called [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), this is the main reason why the changes have not been implemented.

In the screenshot, you can see the file **style.css** for the accordion module under **style1.css** for the template. In the CSS cascade the following order applies: The code of the last file overwrites all the above.

[image]

Two possible solutions:

**- The fast solution:**

Add in your css rule the value **!important**, something like: 
`background-color: #0088cc !important;`

**- The recommended solution:**

Go to the CSS file for the menu and change the value for the background.